# Android ImageButton event does not execute all actions upon first click

Tags: java, android, kotlin, buttonclick, android-imagebutton

I have a button to delete all data on my activity screen (a chart, database data and a textview) and to display a toast.
Pressing the button does everything apart from getting rid of the textview, which only happens upon a second press. The code is in onCreate. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thank you :)

```
findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.delete_btn).setOnClickListener {
   pieChart.visibility = View.GONE
   textView.visibility = View.GONE
   appsViewModel.removeAll()
   Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully deleted all", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: How do you find the other views?

Comment: Can you please give us a bigger picture? Like is there any other place where `textView.visibility` changes? It would be great to have more code. To see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the questions. There is a lot of code I would have to show you and this is a university assignment so I have to keep it minimal. I understand it's harder to visualise though. The visibility of the textview changes in a function called in on create as well. I tried to move this around as to be called afterwards but it did not make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mayurgajra made me realise, some other code interfered with the changes in the textView. I managed to fix this with a boolean. I set it to true within the ImageButton event, and now I only modify the textview visibility in my other code if the boolean is false.

```
private var deleted: Boolean = false
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.delete_btn).setOnClickListener {
            pieChart.visibility = View.GONE
            totalUsage.visibility = View.GONE
            deleted = true
            appsViewModel.removeAll()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully deleted all", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}

private fun otherMethod(){
           ...
           if (!deleted) {
                  totalUsage.text = "Total usage today: $hour"
                  totalUsage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           }
}
```